# Youtube ApiKey Invalid Credentials

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have create an Youtube v3 API key. I have 2 application, in one application it is working. In another I am getting "401 Invalid credential". I tried with 2 different keys and also tried 2 different project with 2 different keys. Still same problem.

I remember when I created an Api Key, I have verify. For second want to do same, but forgot how I did for 1st one.

Can please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Nothing wrong with ApiKey. Before I called Youtube search, I call another service for authentication. it was problem with Cross Domain request (CORS)